# LHCb Peaking Background

Tags: particle-physics, experimental-physics, definition

I was reading a paper on the estimation of the branching fraction of B+ to K pi pi gamma.

I was wondering whether you could clarify the meaning of peaking background.

Thanks!

Comment: A peaking background is a background that has a peak-like shape. Usual sources are "reflections" and misidentified decay modes. A peaking background in the decay mode you mention could be B+ to K K pi gamma where a K is misidentified as a pi.